# Web assembly - integer values wrong

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

In my web assembly application I can not seem to get integers to pass between javascript and c correctly.

```
// C
int *g_id; // Pointer to array of integers (IDs) {0,1,2,3,4,5,6...}

int test(int id) {
  for (int i = 0; i < g_bufSize; i++) {
    if (g_id[i] == id) {
      return g_id[i];
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Javascript call:

```
// JS
ccall("test", "number", ["number"], [2]);
```

I would expect this to return the value at `g_id[2]` which is `2` but it always returns `-1`.

If I always `return g_id[2]` then it returns a large integer like `184638192` except when `i` is `0` when it returns `0`.

If I return a pointer to one of the array elements `return &g_id[2]` then it correctly returns a pointer to the array element which I can dereference with this javascript:

```
// JS
var pointer_return = ccall("test", "number", ["number"], [2]);
var value = Module["HEAPF32"][pointer_return/Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT];
```

This is an okay workaround. However the equality check in the C code still does not work.

I feel like I am misunderstanding something fundamental about passing variables between the C code and JS.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What's your setup code? Because that's not a complete example. Still looks like it should work though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you are assigning the variables to an integer array in C then you must pass them using HEAP32 or some other integer heap. So in this case the final line becomes:

```
var value = Module["HEAP32"][pointer_return/Int32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT];
```